# Tasker programming Help?

Tags: tasker

I am a relatively new tasked user and need a little help. I installed the AutoShortcut plugin to allow Tasker to expand my notifications through the nova shortcut. I would like to have tasker expand the notification bar once on the launch of a certain app, then wait until the app is closed. However, with a simple launch app>expand notifications>stop task, the notification bar will continue to drop down over and over because the app is still open. How can I configure tasker to expans the notifications only ONCE, and then not again until the app has closed?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an If statement to the task that checks if a variable is set, if it is not, set the variable and execute task, if it is end task.